# unit test for web socket in node is it possible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, websocket

im running unit test using mocha/supertest/chai and I want to test the following code so my question how should I simulate the **upgrade** event?

```
const http = require('http');
const app = require('./app');
const server = http.createServer(app);

var webSocket = function (server) {
    server.on('upgrade', function (req, socket, head) {
    //I want to enter here...
```

Comment: can't you just pull the logic out of that binding. And then test the function independently? You don't want to start trying to simulate websocket, because you're not testing that.

Comment: @CallumLinington - yes of course I can do that :) but there is no way to make this code works as upgrade ? I mean by code from outside as unit test...